# Exts4 MVC, How to grep textfield in controller

Tags: extjs4

In view,

```
{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   fieldLabel: 'Test Field',
   name: 'testField'
}
```

I want to grep that textfield in controller to hook Keyup event.

I tried,

```
this.control({
  'input[name='testfield']' : {
     afterrender : function(c){
        console.log(c); // nothing happened.
        c.getEl().on('keyup', function (evt, el) {
                console.log(evt.getKey());
        });
     }
  }
});
```

but it does not work,

How can I grep that textbox in controller and hook keyup event?

Anybody know, please advise me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
this.control({
  'textfield[name='testfield']' : {
     afterrender : function(c){
        console.log(c); // nothing happened.
        c.getEl().on('keyup', function (evt, el) {
                console.log(evt.getKey());
        });
     }
  }
});
```

you've specified `input` instead of `textfield`.

The selectors that you specify in the `this.control` function should conform to those accepted by `Ext.ComponentQuery`. Check [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control)